# SymPy: How to make `nsolve` return a dictionary with the found solutions

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I want to use `nsolve` as a fallback to `solve` and like to use `dict = True` to make `solve` return a dictionary with the found solutions and corresponding variables. However, `nsolve` doesn't seem to have this option.

**This is what I'm using as a workaround:**

```
from sympy import *

def nsolve(equations, variables, guesses, **flags):
    from sympy import nsolve as originalnsolve
    result = originalnsolve(equations, variables, guesses, **flags)
    if "dict" in flags and flags["dict"]:
        return [dict(zip(variables, [float(value) for value in result]))]
    else:
        return result

x, y = symbols("x y")
equations = [Eq(2*x+y, 3), Eq(y-x, 1)]
variables = [x, y]
guesses = [1, 1]

print("solve with dict = True produces:\n%s\n" % solve(equations, variables, dict = True) + "The result is a dictionary, as needed\n")
print("nsolve without dict = True produces:\n%s\n" % nsolve(equations, variables, guesses) + "nsolve doesn't return a dictionary\n")
print("nsolve with dict = True produces:\n%s\n" % nsolve(equations, variables, guesses, dict = True) + "My workaround wrapper function returns a dictionary\n")
```

**The output would be:**

```
solve with dict = True produces:
[{x: 2/3, y: 5/3}]
The result is a dictionary, as needed

nsolve without dict = True produces:
[0.666666666666667]
[ 1.66666666666667]
nsolve doesn't return a dictionary

nsolve with dict = True produces:
[{x: 0.6666666666666666, y: 1.6666666666666667}]
My workaround wrapper function returns a dictionary
```

**My questions:**

- Am I missing a simpler method to make `nsolve` return a dictionary?
- And if not: is something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nsolve` doesn't have a `dict` option. If you want to request one, you should open a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new), or a pull request that implements it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your response. I might just try that then. ;-) [#12397](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12397)